# Links exceed text margins when using `authoryear` or `authoryear-comp` citation styles in `biblatex`

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

When I use `biblatex` with `authoryear` or `authoryear-comp` options, the links may go beyond the margin specified for text body. Other styles seem to be working normally.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@online{lovelace2015low,
    author = {Lovelace, Will},
    title = {{Low SCR Wind Integration and Mitigation}},
    url = {http://www.cce.umn.edu/documents/CPE-Conferences/MIPSYCON-PowerPoints/2015/PGLowSCRWindGenerationInstabilityIdentificationandMitigation.pdf},
    organization = {Minnkota Power Cooperative},
    date = {2015-11-11},
    urldate = {2019-05-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{lovelace2015low}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `xurl` (after `biblatex`):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
    @online{lovelace2015low,
        author = {Lovelace, Will},
        title = {{Low SCR Wind Integration and Mitigation}},
        url={http://www.cce.umn.edu/documents/CPE-Conferences/MIPSYCON-PowerPoints/2015/PGLowSCRWindGenerationInstabilityIdentificationandMitigation.pdf},
        organization = {Minnkota Power Cooperative},
        date = {2015-11-11},
        urldate = {2019-05-20}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{lovelace2015low}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]